# while importing SugarCRM package, Getting an Error "Inconsistent class hierarchy" in respective "SugarsoapBindingStub.java"

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, maven, jar

Did anybody have solution How to remove that error, Although i have imported following recommended library for this purpose to solve. I am eagerly waiting for solution!

- axis.jar
- axis-1.4.jar
- axis-jaxrpc-1.2.1.jar
- axis-saaj-1.2.1.jar
- commons-discovery-0.2.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3-bin.jar
- jaxrpc.jar
- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- wsdl4j.jar
- wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar

This package is present on following link.
http://linkwithweb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CRM/SugarCRM/JavaSOAPClient/SugarCRMClient/src/com/sugarcrm/www/sugarcrm/

Comment: you got this error in eclipse ? or with maven command line ? or both ?

Comment: it's strange to have both `axis.jar` and àxis-1.4.jar` in your classpath. (same remark for `wsdl4j`). `jaxrpc.jar` is not a valid name for maven dependency: try to use maven equivalent libraries (i.e. `jaxrpc-api` + some jaxrpc implementation suitable for your needs).

Comment: Hi Ben I am getting this error in eclipse.